# How to make specific traffic not go through the VPN in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I am using windows 10, and the problem is whenever I run my VPN (Cisco), I can't access my router web console (192.168.1.1), and I have to disconnect my VPN first.
I also add this route to my windows, but it doesn't work.

```
route -p add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

What should I do?
PS: My VPN has created a network adapter for itself, as you can see:

[image]

Comment: Is there a setting in AnyConnect for Split Tunnel.

Comment: No, it isn't, It just has a separate adapter

Comment: You will have to talk to your system administrator about configuring your vpn connection to allow what your attempting to do.